# How to save docker large image?

Tags: docker, centos7

I can not save large size image on docker (larger than 10G, surely, I can save normal size image.).

I got this error.

> "Error response from daemon: write
>   /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-export-583646400/c5d6f85cecb634a672016d4f45f80546c00de75c1cf03166ea0f8b04d31f5ae0/layer.tar:
>   no space left on device "

My storage driver is overlay2(Can not change the base size Base device size?). I do not know this information is useful. Anyway, if you have some advices, plese teach me.

I attach information about docker info.

```
Containers: 1
Running: 0  
Paused: 0  
Stopped: 1 
Images: 4 
Server Version: 18.09.0 
Storage Driver: overlay2  
Backing Filesystem: xfs  
Supports d_type: true  
Native Overlay Diff: true 
Logging Driver: json-file 
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs 
Plugins:  
Volume: local  
Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay  
Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog 
Swarm: inactive 
Runtimes: runc 
Default Runtime: runc 
Init Binary: docker-init containerd 
version: c4446665cb9c30056f4998ed953e6d4ff22c7c39 
runc version: 4fc53a81fb7c994640722ac585fa9ca548971871 
init version: fec3683 
Security Options:  seccomp   
Profile: default 
Kernel Version: 3.10.0-862.14.4.el7.x86_64 
Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core) 
OSType: linux 
Architecture: x86_64 
CPUs: 8 
Total Memory: 22.4GiB 
Name: git.for.ota 
ID: 3WCV:4BPQ:LTO3:FYQB:7PAK:4NH6:GUFH:XKZ5:UGZJ:JICV:MTU5:ROUE 
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker 
Debug Mode (client): false Debug Mode (server): false 
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/                  
Labels:                                                                
Experimental: false 
Insecure Registries: 127.0.0.0/8                                                                                                                                                  
Live Restore Enabled: false                                            
Product License: Community Engine
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't create such large images, keep docker images as small as it possible.

Second, the issue that you have is actually with the configuration of overlay2 storage itself (by default 10Gb).

Comment: The overlay storage drivers use very special directories on the host system; unless the devicemapper driver they don't have a dedicated limited storage space.  In any case this is failing (with a very very clear error) trying to create a giant tar file in `/var/lib/docker/tmp`, outside the Docker storage space.